# Install Modeler Salesforce CLI Plugin (Vs Code)

Tags: vs-code, mobile, sfdx-plugin

we are working on Visual Studio Code Based Modeler for Consumer Goods
Cloud and an update was made in the plugins for salesforce modeler, and it did not work correctly.

I reinstalled the plugin as mentioned in the documentation and now it is not possible to install it.

Is there a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding the error you mentioned in the ss

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. The issue may be with the Python and Miscrosoft Build Tools. There is a possibility that it wasn't installed correctly. I suggest following the below steps. I am assuming you already have Node.js installed. Note that I use Windows 10 x64

1. In your Windows search box, type "Windows PowerShell".

2.Right-click "Windows PowerShell", then select "Run as administrator".

3.On the pop-up screen, select "Yes".

4. In the Command Prompt, run  "choco upgrade chocolatey" to upgrade the Chocolatey package.
5. Run  "choco install python --pre"  to install Python. Each time you are asked, “Do you want to run this script”, enter "Y" for yes.
6. Run "choco install visualstudio2019-workload-vctools" to install Visual C++ build tools workload for Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools. Each time you are asked, “Do you want to run this script”, enter "Y" for yes.
7. Manually Set Environment Variables.

Variable Name: "VCTargetsPath"
Variable Value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160"

8. Run "npm install @salesforce/cli --global" to install Salesforce CLI with npm
9. Go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ to install version 3.11.0 of Python
10. Configure CORS Allowlist. http://localhost:3000
11. Finally, run "sf plugins install @ind-rcg/modeler-sfdx-cli-plugin" to install the modeler plugin.